# Calling upon Variables/dataframes from a reactive dataframe

Tags: r, shiny

Let's say I have the following reactive portion of my shiny app:

```
    data1 <- reactive({

        if(input$plotbutton == 0){return()}
        inFile <- input$file1
        if (is.null(inFile)){return(NULL)}


          # Read CSV    
          df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = TRUE, sep = ",")
          df <- df[, c(1, 28:29)]


          # Convert df[1] from Factor to Character
          i <- sapply(df, is.factor)
          df[i] <- lapply(df[i], as.character)


          # Extract Depth From df[1]
          readingdepth <- c(word(df[,1],-1))
          readingdepth = as.numeric(readingdepth)

})
```

Let's say that I want to use `readingdepth` later in a `renderPlot`. How would I go about calling upon this from `data1()` to make it usable? Is it something like `data1()$readingdepth[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case i would put: `return(readingdepth)` at the final of the reactive function and then when u make the renderplot just call the function `data1()` and assign a variable like `x <- data1()` (inside the renderplot function).

Then u will be able to use it. Otherwise you can make another reactive function and put the code to do the readingdepth again and also put the `return(readingdepth)`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've done `return(readingdepth)` and assigned `x <- data1()` within renderPlot, but how do I call upon `readingdepth` correctly? Is it `data1()$readingdepth` ?

Comment: no, your function returns de readingdepth so there's no point to use data1()$readingdepth (bad form)